# QGIS plugin saving layerstyle

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I tried to use:

```
Error = ""

vLayer.saveStyleToDatabase  ("styleName", "description", True, "", Error)
```

in a python-plugin for QGIS 2.6 to save the data but no success.

No error is written. First of all , where should the table be? I think it's supposed to be in the datasource-db (sqlite) but I can't find any information.

Any help?

Comment: Hi norbert, I edited your question to what I think you are trying to ask. Please edit it if I am mistaken in my understanding. Also, I do not know the answer to this so hopefully others can advise =)

Answer (score 0):

The code checks for errors by doing

```
if ( !msgError.isNull() )
```

Declare Error = None instead of Error = ""